# Ruby on Rails starts very slowly on FreeBSD

Tags: ruby-on-rails, freebsd

I've been running Ruby on Rails on FreeBSD. It takes 10-20 seconds just to load the environment. Is there anything that I can do to make it load faster, or is FreeBSD just not a good platform for Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Just to get more information I would compare the time it takes to load Ruby itself (either ruby or irb) to another platform to see whether the problem is Ruby or Rails.

Comment: It might be that either ruby is slow on FreeBSD (grab some benchmarks, compare them), or that your project ist just big. Our here takes ~ 30 secs to spin up...

Answer (score 1):

Phusion's Ruby Enterprise Edition compiles on FreeBSD and runs faster with lower memory usage. There's no port for it (yet), but you can download it from their site and just run the install script.